# How to schedule notifications daily for prayer times automatically in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, package, notifications

I am using adhan dart package to get prayer times and scheduled notifications using flutterlocalnotification.zonedscedule().The problem is if user clicks on schedule notification button then only that day he will get notifications for prayer times. But I want when user installs app and clicks on schedule notification button then he will gets notification daily automatically at prayer times which are getting from adhan dart package.

Here is my notification service class

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:islamic/getprayertime.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  static final NotificationService _notificationService =
      NotificationService._internal();

  factory NotificationService() {
    return _notificationService;
  }

  NotificationService._internal();

  Future<void> initializenotification() async {
    //Android Platform configuration required to send notifications
    AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('logo');
    InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidInitializationSettings);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  backgroundtask() {
    Prayers.getPrayertimes().then((value) {
      final currenttime = DateTime.now();
      if (value.fajr!.toLocal().isAfter(currenttime)) {
        schedulePrayerTimeNotification(value.fajr!.toLocal(), 'Fajr');
      }

      if (value.dhuhr!.toLocal().isAfter(currenttime)) {
        schedulePrayerTimeNotification(value.dhuhr!.toLocal(), 'Dhuhr');
      }

      if (value.asr!.toLocal().isAfter(currenttime)) {
        schedulePrayerTimeNotification(value.asr!.toLocal(), 'Asr');
      }

      if (value.maghrib!.toLocal().isAfter(currenttime)) {
        schedulePrayerTimeNotification(value.maghrib!.toLocal(), 'Maghrib');
      }

      if (value.isha!.toLocal().isAfter(currenttime)) {
        schedulePrayerTimeNotification(value.isha!.toLocal(), 'Isha');
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> schedulePrayerTimeNotification(
      DateTime prayerTime, String prayerName) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'main_channel',
      'Main Channel',
      channelDescription: "ashwin",
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.max,
    );

    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

    final formattedTime = DateFormat('h:mm a').format(prayerTime);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      prayerName.hashCode,
      'Prayer Time',
      'It\'s time for $prayerName prayer at $formattedTime.',
      tz.TZDateTime.from(prayerTime, tz.local),
      notificationDetails,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true, //to show notification when app is closed
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my home class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:islamic/background_task.dart';
import 'package:islamic/drawer.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        ),
        
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 60,
            width: 300,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.snackbar(
                  'Prayer reminder',
                  'Your prayer reminder has been created',
                  snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.mosque),
                );
                NotificationService().backgroundtask();
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.indigo),
              child: Text(
                'Set Prayer reminder',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I do that Anyone can help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `android_alarm_manager_plus` package in order to schedule daily prayer time notifications.

1. Add the android_alarm_manager_plus package to your pubspec.yaml file
2. You can schedule the alarm when the user clicks the "schedule notification" button. The `homepage.dart` must be

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:islamic/notification_service.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  List<String> scheduledPrayers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadScheduledPrayers();
  }

  Future<void> loadScheduledPrayers() async {
    final prayers = await NotificationService().getScheduledPrayerTimes();
    setState(() {
      scheduledPrayers = prayers;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.snackbar(
                  'Prayer reminder',
                  'Your prayer reminder has been created',
                  snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.mosque),
                );

                // Schedule the daily recurring alarm
                AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
                  const Duration(hours: 24), // repeat daily
                  0, // alarm ID
                  NotificationService().backgroundTask, // callback method
                  exact: true,
                  wakeup: true,
                );
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.indigo),
              child: Text(
                'Set Prayer reminder',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: scheduledPrayers.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(scheduledPrayers[index]),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

3. The `notification_service.dart` must be:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:islamic/getprayertime.dart';
import 'package:android_alarm_manager_plus/android_alarm_manager_plus.dart'; // Import the alarm manager package
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  static final NotificationService _notificationService =
      NotificationService._internal();

  factory NotificationService() {
    return _notificationService;
  }

  NotificationService._internal();

  Future<void> initializenotification() async {
    // Android Platform configuration required to send notifications
    AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('logo');
    InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidInitializationSettings);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  Future<void> saveScheduledPrayerTime(
      DateTime prayerTime, String prayerName) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final notifications = prefs.getStringList('scheduled_prayers') ?? [];

    final formattedTime = DateFormat('h:mm a').format(prayerTime);
    final notificationData = '$prayerName - $formattedTime';

    notifications.add(notificationData);
    await prefs.setStringList('scheduled_prayers', notifications);
  }

  Future<List<String>> getScheduledPrayerTimes() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getStringList('scheduled_prayers') ?? [];
  }

  backgroundTask() async {
    Prayers.getPrayertimes().then((value) {
      final currenttime = DateTime.now();
      if (value.fajr!.toLocal().isAfter(currenttime)) {
        schedulePrayerTimeNotification(value.fajr!.toLocal(), 'Fajr');
        saveScheduledPrayerTime(value.fajr!.toLocal(), 'Fajr');
      }
      if (value.dhuhr!.toLocal().isAfter(currenttime)) {
        schedulePrayerTimeNotification(value.dhuhr!.toLocal(), 'Dhuhr');
        saveScheduledPrayerTime(value.dhuhr!.toLocal(), 'Dhuhr');
      }
      if (value.asr!.toLocal().isAfter(currenttime)) {
        schedulePrayerTimeNotification(value.asr!.toLocal(), 'Asr');
        saveScheduledPrayerTime(value.asr!.toLocal(), 'Asr');
      }
      if (value.maghrib!.toLocal().isAfter(currenttime)) {
        schedulePrayerTimeNotification(value.maghrib!.toLocal(), 'Maghrib');
        saveScheduledPrayerTime(value.maghrib!.toLocal(), 'Maghrib');
      }
      if (value.isha!.toLocal().isAfter(currenttime)) {
        schedulePrayerTimeNotification(value.isha!.toLocal(), 'Isha');
        saveScheduledPrayerTime(value.isha!.toLocal(), 'Isha');
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> schedulePrayerTimeNotification(
      DateTime prayerTime, String prayerName) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'main_channel',
      'Main Channel',
      channelDescription: "ashwin",
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.max,
    );

    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

    final formattedTime = DateFormat('h:mm a').format(prayerTime);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      prayerName.hashCode,
      'Prayer Time',
      'It\'s time for $prayerName prayer at $formattedTime.',
      tz.TZDateTime.from(prayerTime, tz.local),
      notificationDetails,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true, // to show notification when the app is closed
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }
}
```

In order to update the list view when the user clicks the schedule notification button, you can call the `loadScheduledPrayers()` method again after scheduling the alarm.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:android_alarm_manager_plus/android_alarm_manager_plus.dart';
import 'package:islamic/notification_service.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {

  List<String> scheduledPrayers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadScheduledPrayers();
  }

  Future<void> loadScheduledPrayers() async {
    final prayers = await NotificationService().getScheduledPrayerTimes();
    setState(() {
      scheduledPrayers = prayers;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {

              // Schedule alarm  
              await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
                Duration(hours: 24),
                0,
                NotificationService().backgroundTask,
                exact: true,
                wakeup: true,
              );
              
              // Reload scheduled prayers  
              await loadScheduledPrayers();

             // Call setState
              setState(() {}); 

            },
            child: Text('Schedule Notifications'),
          ),

          // List scheduled prayers
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: scheduledPrayers.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(scheduledPrayers[index]),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Kindly, let me know if it works.

Comment: You don't need to call initializenotification() within your app's initialization. kindly clear that point

Comment: void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationService().initializenotification();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
Are you talking about Notificationservice().initializenotification() in main?

Comment: After having a look at your `main()`, you need to call `Notificationservice().initializenotification()` the way you already doing. Kindly, add the full dart code in question as well. I have also updated the answer.

Comment: I am checking it i will inform you soon

Comment: you load the savescheduled prayers in initstate and i also want to update list in homepage when user clicks on schedule notification then listview builder also updated at that time

Comment: brother it does not update list when button clicks

Comment: @AbdullahShahzad add  `setState(() {});` this line after this ` await loadScheduledPrayers();` line in the `onPressed` method. I have also updated the code. I am positive that it will work.

Comment: same problem i think loadprayer called before saving data to sharedpreference